# pass 2 objects to jquery.css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

on my way to the shortest code on urff.

i have an object, where i make a feature detection. i then pass the result to a jquery.css() command. but i do have some other css rules, that i need to apply, too. i cant put them into the object, cause these rules differ from time to time. so i now pass two jquery.css() commands, but im trying to make one out of it, just for the sexyness..

```
var myObject  = (Modernizr.csstransforms ? {transform: 'translateX(123px)'} : {left: 123});
$("#elem").css(myObject).css({ sexyness: 0 });
```

while i try to make it something like this:

```
$("#elem").css(myObject, { sexyness: "100%" });
```

am i missing something, or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: You should avoid using `css` as much as possible. If you need it for dynamic values, so be it, but for static styles you should be using `addClass`, `removeClass`, and `toggleClass`.

Comment: thanks. its dynamic, the code above is just an example..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to merge those two css property objects

```
$("#elem").css($.extend({}, myObject, { sexyness: "100%" }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need "glue" objects and use new object for set style. Looks like this:

#### fixed

```
$.extend(myObject, { sexyness: "100%" });
$("#elem").css(myObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#elem").css($.extend({}, myObject, { sexyness: "100%" }));
```

[jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong  :( Misread the API 
<strike>jQuery 1.9 allows you to use arrays of properties, so you can do:</strike>

```
var myObject  = (Modernizr.csstransforms ? 
                          ["transform: translateX(123px)"] : 
                          ["left: 123"]);
$("#elem").css(myObject.add("sexyness: 80"))
```

Lets cheat and use JSON.parse, which lets us simply concatenate strings

```
var myObject  = (Modernizr.csstransforms ? 
                 'transform: "translateX(123px),"'} : 
                 'left: 123,');
$("#elem").css(JSON.parse(myObject + 'sexyness : 80'))
```